# Ruby regexp to match comma, but ignore comma in brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to split a parameter list by regexp.

This is a string with my parameter list:

```
"a = b, c = 3, d = [1,3,5,7], e, f = g"
```

What I want is:

```
["a = b", "c = 3", "d = [1,3,5,7]", "e", "f = g"]
```

I tried with a lookahead, but Ruby doesn't allow lookbehinds with a dynamic range, so this won't work:

```
/(?<!\[),(?!\w*\])/
```

How can I tell the regexp to ignore everything in square brackets?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have an "=" in each split you want from the input? There could be better solutions to do what you want if you could post all the constraints.

Comment: @Casimir, not sure why you removed the quotes from the input, it's a string, and that's clearer when surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: @Dogbert and Casimir That's why I put the quotes in there.

Comment: @Dogbert I am not guaranteed to have an "=" in each split. I edited my question to include a split without "=".

Comment: I just want to mention that this isn't really what Regular Expressions are for, they are mor for defining how a string should look and extracting data from a formatted string. Parsing strings is better left to some form of tokenizer or parser that knows how to break the string into tokens which is what you're after.

Comment: @Dogbert: you are right, i put them back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like that would work for you:

```
 str.scan(/(?:\[.*?\]|[^,])+/)
```

**EDIT** after second thought.

Simple non-greedy matcher will fail in some cases of nested parentheses.

Comment: This. I like this. Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: Be careful, check out my edit. I noticed this solution is not viable for every case.

Comment: Nested parantheses aren't allowed in this case, so it shouldn't be a problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: you can also do `str.scan /[^,]*\[.*?\]|[^,]+/`

Comment: I would like to ignore `,` when is inside `{}` too. This is the regex `(?:(\[|\{).*?(\]|\})|[^,])+`, it should  be ok?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to get it all done with one splitting regex, you could split, then correct your array of pairs.

```
input = "a = b, c = 3, d = [1,5], e = f"
pairs = input.split(/,\s*/)
pairs.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if index > 0 && (item =~ /=/).nil?
    pairs[index - 1] += ',' + item
    pairs[index] = nil
  end
end
pairs.delete_if { |item| item.nil? }
puts pairs
```

Outputs:

```
a = b
c = 3
d = [1,5]
e = f
```

Comment: This is my current solution, but I asked myself, if it is possible in one step.